# Offline deployment of python scypy and django

Tags: python, django, deployment, scipy

I've got a django/pandas/scipy application. I need to deploy them on a Windows Server 2012 machine without Internet access.

So, I can't make a pip install in that machine. Furthermore, to install numpy, scipy and more, some of the libraries need to compile some libraries like openblas and more, so deployment is a nightmare. You need too many things to do for this deployment.

Docker is not an option. I've got a VM right now, but I want to get rid of it.

Is there any posibility to encapsulate a python - scipy to make a deployment on a machine without making it a real nightmare?

Comment: Have you looked into [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) or other recommendations in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen ?